# How to Set Console Buffer Size

Tags: c++, windows, buffer

I'm trying to change the size of the buffer in the windows console. I keep getting an error 87, which means a parameter is incorrect. I have a COORD, and a the correct handle. I don't know what's wrong.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),{10,10});
    int e = GetLastError();
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
    cout << e << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `GetLastError()` will only be meaningful if `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` returns 0, which you are not checking for, otherwise the error code will be from an earlier indeterminate API call.

Comment: NB: The specified width and height cannot be less than the width and height of the console screen buffer's window